# Any logical test to distinguish between make-up of numerical objects

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if there a way for `R` to **detect** the existence or absence of the sign `*` as used in the following objects?

In other words, can R understand that `a` has a `*` sign but `b` doesn't?

```
a = 3*4
b = 12
```

Comment: Why doesn't `a` have 4 elements?

Comment: @BenBolker's answer is excellent, but it sounds like you're looking for something very specific. Give us the rest of your problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you keep the expressions *unevaluated*, R can understand their internal complexity. Under normal circumstances, though, R evaluates expressions immediately, so there is no way to tell the difference between `a <- 3*4` and `b <- 12` once the assignments have been made. That means that the answer to your specific question is **No**.

Dealing with unevaluated expressions can get a bit complex, but `quote()` is one simple way to keep e.g. `3*4` from being evaluated:

```
 > length(quote(3*4))
[1] 3
> length(quote(12))
[1] 1
```

If you're working inside a function, you can use `substitute` to retrieve the unevaluated form of the function arguments:

```
> f <- function(a) {
+    length(substitute(a))
+ }
> f(12)
[1] 1
> f(3*4)
[1] 3
```

In case you're pursuing this farther, you should be aware that counting complexity might not be as easy as you think:

```
> f(sqrt(2*3+(7*19)^2))
[1] 2
```

What's going on is that R stores expressions as a *tree*; the top level here is made up of `sqrt` and `<the rest of the expression>`, which has length 2. If you want to measure complexity you'll need to do some kind of collapsing or counting down the branches of the tree ...

Furthermore, if you first assign `a <- 3*4` and then call `f(a)` you get 1, not 3, because `substitute()` gives you back just the *symbol* `a`, which has length 1 ... the information about the difference between "12" and "3*4" gets lost **as soon as the expression is evaluated**, which happens when the value is assigned to the symbol `a`. The bottom line is that you have to be very careful in controlling when expressions get evaluated, and it's not easy.

Hadley Wickham's [chapter on expressions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html) might be a good place to read more.

Comment: Ben, BUT, `f(a)` doesn't return `3`!?

Comment: nope. I was just getting around to explaining that.

Comment: this stuff gets extremely tricky. You might need to edit your question (or post a new question) to explain *exactly* what you're trying to do.